# Tomee - Hibernate logger config

Tags: hibernate, apache-tomee

Is there some type of default hibernate logging config that comes with tomee?  I'm not getting any error when using hibernate to access mysql table from a standalone application.  But when I port the same code into a web app that runs in tomee, I'm getting error below.  It appears to be caused by something is being config to use hsqldb to do hibernate logging.  But I've never done any such config in hibernate or tomee.

```
Feb 7, 2015 8:40:38 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
Feb 7, 2015 8:40:38 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 7, 2015 8:40:39 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 7, 2015 8:40:39 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Feb 7, 2015 8:40:40 AM org.hsqldb.persist.Logger logSevereEvent
SEVERE: could not reopen database
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@467d8301[file =C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\data\hsqldb\hsqldb.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\data\hsqldb\hsqldb.lck (Access is denied)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile.newLockFileLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.acquireLock(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.persist.Logger.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.reopen(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Database.open(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.newSession(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:86)
at org.apache.openejb.resource.jdbc.managed.local.ManagedDataSource.getConnection(ManagedDataSource.java:56)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:55)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:101)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:150)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:752)
at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:612)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1213)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1054)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

TomEE provides you a default datasource (hsqldb). I guess you use javax.persistence properties and not jta-data-source/non-jta-data-source tag to setup your mysql connection in your persistence unit.